# WinForms ListView empty rows glitch

Tags: winforms, listview

I have a glitch in a WinForms C# ListView (with custom modifications to sort and filters on all columns, but it happened also in a standard ListView).

I modify the ListView Items with this (fairly standard) pattern:

```
BeginUpdate();
// add some items
// remove some other items
Sort();
EndUpdate();
```

But if I call this code when the ListView is already scrolled, then I get some empty (non selectable) rows before the real items, and 2 scrollabars even if they are not needed.

It looks like a graphic glitch, because when I scroll the list then the empty items disappear.

Have anyone met this problem before?

Comment: This kind of obscure problem requires a repro project to narrow down the possible causes.  Long shot: EndUpdate() already call Sort(), omit your call and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Already removed Sort(), no difference.

I am testing with a small project, and I cannot reproduce the issue, so there's definitly something wrong with my code, but I wanted to check if someone knew of such a glitch

thanks a lot

Comment: 11 years have past and this bug is still present in the latest .NET

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the problem. A call to set a column Width = -2 during Resize was messing the owner-draw filters...

Answer (score 1):

This ListView graphic bug. A similar problem can be reproduced, if while changing the ListView size, change the width of its columns. As a solution, the method proposes to change the width in a separate thread.

```
private void ListView_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var widthChangedThread = new Thread(() => SetNewColumnSize()) {IsBackground = true};   
    widthChangedThread.Start();              
}

private void SetNewColumnSize()
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>_columnHeader.Width += 10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This control behave in a strange way but setting up the scrollabe
property to false in the resize event fixed completly the problem as:

```
With DirectCast(sender, ListView)
      'do not allow scrolling in the resize event
      'ortherwise there is a condition where the control 
      'stop showing the row data
      IsScrollEnabled = .Scrollable
      .Scrollable = False
      ThisColumnHeader = .Columns("colMessage")
      If ThisColumnHeader IsNot Nothing Then
        .BeginUpdate()
        'With .Columns("colMessage")
        '  .Width = -2
        'End With
        If .Items.Count > 0 Then
          'If MyListDownloadMessage.Count > 0 Then
          If ToolStripSerialRxFillDown.Checked Then
            .EnsureVisible(.Items.Count - 1)
          Else
            If .TopItem IsNot Nothing Then
              .EnsureVisible(.TopItem.Index)
            End If
          End If
        End If
        .EndUpdate()
        .Refresh()
      End If
      .Scrollable = IsScrollEnabled
    End With
```